# Adding a TabBarController as the Subview of a View

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, frame, bounds

I am loading a splash screen when my app starts.   Then I want to load  a TabBarController and it's ViewControllers.  However, my TabBarController window does not scale to the screen size.

Probably 3/4 of the TabBar at the bottom is getting cut off and There is a slim aprox 20 pixel gap at the top of the screen below the status bar.  How do I resize the TabBarController properly?

Here is the code in my SplashViewController loading the splash view, and the TabBarController:

```
 -(void)loadView{
// Init the view
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appFrame];
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.view = view;
[view release];

splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash.png"]];
splashImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,458);
[self.view addSubview:splashImageView];

viewController = [[FlashCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlashCardViewController"  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
//viewController.view.bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
viewController.title = @"Quiz";
viewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puzzle.png"];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil  bundle:nil];
viewController2.title = @"Nada";
viewController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"magnifying-glass.png"];
//viewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
//[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, viewController2, nil];
[viewController2 release];
tabBarController.view.alpha = 0.0;
//tabBarController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"State_California.png"];
//tabBarController.tabBarItem.title = @"State_California.png";
tabBarController.view.bounds = [[self view] bounds];
//tabBarController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; 
}
-(void) fadeScreen
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; // begin animation block
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75]; // sets animation duration
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; // sets the delegate for this block
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finishedFading)]; // Calls finishFading
self.view.alpha = 0.0; //  // Fades the alpha to 0 over animation
[UIView commitAnimations]; // Commits this block, done
}

-(void) finishedFading
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; // Begin animation block
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75]; // set duration
self.view.alpha = 1.0; // fades the view to 1.0 alpha over .75 seconds
//viewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
tabBarController.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[splashImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found someting that works.  Instead of:

```
tabBarController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

or

```
tabBarController.view.bounds = [[self view] bounds];
```

Because I couldn't find and automatic or named settings for this size, I had to create my own rectangle that is the size of the screen minus the statusBar.

```
 tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
```

Comment: If you run self.tabBarController.view.frame = [[self view] frame] in viewWillAppear it will work without you having to work out the numbers yourself because at that point the bounds and frame have been properly/fully calculated.

Comment: would this be better answer: tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); since the width and height vary accordingly to each device the user is using?

Answer (score 12):

I've just completed pretty much the same and ran into the same problems but eventually I got it working.

1. Create a View Controller class in Xcode called `Test1ViewController` and add the following:

   ```
   @interface Test1ViewController : UIViewController {
       IBOutlet UITabBarController *tbc;
   }

   @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tbc;
   @end
   ```
2. Create a View XIB called `Test1View`
3. Add a `TabBarViewController` to the XIB
4. Set the File's Owner in the XIB to be the `Test1ViewController`.
5. Connect the `tbc` IBOutlet in the File's Owner to the Tab Bar Controller in the XIB.
6. Connect the `view` IBOutlet in the File's Owner to the View in the XIB.
7. In your SplashViewController.h add the property

   ```
   Test1ViewController *tabBarViewController;
   ```
8. Synthesize the `tabBarViewController` in your `SplashViewController.m`.
9. Replace your `TabBarController` creation code in your `loadView` method in `SplashViewController` with the following:

   ```
   tabBarViewController = [[Test1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
           @"Test1View" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   tabBarViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
   [self.view addSubview:[tabBarViewController view]];
   ```
10. Here's the bit that was missing for me. In `Test1ViewController.m`, you need to add the following line to the `viewDidLoad` method:

    ```
    self.view = tbc.view;
    ```
11. Finally, I also had to change the `finishedFading` method in `SplashViewController.m` to set the alpha to 1.0 on the `tabBarViewController` view.

    ```
    -(void) finishedFading
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
        self.view.alpha = 1.0;
        tabBarViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [splashImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something similar. Rated the thing up.

Comment: Thanks! I could not for the life of me get it working, turns out I was missing step 10.

Comment: Almost everything in this answer was dead-on other than step 10. For some reason that just doesn't work now, perhaps its an iOS5 thing? Instead placing self.tabBarController.view.frame = [[self view] frame] in viewWillAppear did the trick for me.