# How to add a subview to a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I am trying to add a UITabBarController to a UIViewController:

```
[self.view addSubView:tabBarController.view];
```

I get a warning:

```
warning: 'UIView' may not respond to '-addSubView:'
```

How can I add a UITabBarController to my UIViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific warning you are getting is because you are spelling the method name wrong; try `addSubview:` instead of `addSubView:`.

But, aside from that problem, you may still have difficulty getting the UITabBarController to work correctly in a subview, because it's not intended to be used that way. The [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW13) says:

> When deploying a tab bar interface,
>   you must install this view as the root
>   of your window. Unlike other view
>   controllers, a tab bar interface
>   should never be installed as a child
>   of another view controller.

Comment: What happens if I add it as a subview of a ViewController and now the root of my window?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329560/adding-a-tabbarcontroller-as-the-subview-of-a-view might give you some pointers on what you you might run into and how to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

*emphasized text*replace with this----

[self.view **addSubview**:obj.view];